# Team Foundation Version Control Commands

Tags: team-foundation-server

Does anyone know if the following commands are detailed or listed in any tables or config files?

Table: tbl_Version
Field: Command

- List item
- Edit = 2
- Type = 4
- Add folder = 5
- Add file = 7
- Rename = 8
- Rename,edit = 10
- Delete = 16
- Delete,rename = 24
- Undelete = 32
- Undelete,edit = 34
- Branch = 68
- Branch,delete = 84
- Merge = 128
- Merge, edit = 130
- Merge,type,edit = 134
- Merge, rename, edit = 138
- Merge,delete = 144
- Merge,delete,rename = 152
- Merge,undelete = 160
- Merge,undelete,edit = 162
- Merge,branch = 196
- Merge,branch,edit = 198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is trying to query against tbl_Version (TFS 2017 Update3), the enum bits [shown by Jesse](https://serverfault.com/a/902181/283889) should be shifted one place in the database. I'm not sure why the ChangeType enum would be setup as Jesse describes, as it would violate [.NET design guideline CA1008](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1008) and common sense by apparently setting 'None'=1 instead of 0. This makes [Rick Web's values](https://serverfault.com/q/898557/283889) pretty close to correct. The bit flags of the 'Command' col in the DB are therefore:

```
(None = 0)
Add = 1,
Edit = 2,
Encoding = 4,
Rename = 8,
Delete = 16,
Undelete = 32
Branch = 64,
Merge = 128,
Lock = 256,
Rollback = 512,
SourceRename = 1024,
Property = 4096
```

Here's some crappy SQL to decode them as a space-separated list in your SELECT-

```
SELECT TOP 10 RTRIM(
    CASE WHEN Command & 1 = 1 THEN 'Add ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 2 = 2 THEN 'Edit ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 4 = 4 THEN 'Encoding ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 8 = 8 THEN 'Rename ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 16 = 16 THEN 'Delete ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 32 = 32 THEN 'Undelete ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 64 = 64 THEN 'Branch ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 128 = 128 THEN 'Merge ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 256 = 256 THEN 'Lock ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 512 = 512 THEN 'Rollback ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 1024 = 1024 THEN 'SourceRename ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 2048 = 2048 THEN 'UNKNOWN ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 4096 = 4096 THEN 'Property ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 8192 = 8192 THEN 'UNKNOWN ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Command & 16384 = 16384 THEN 'UNKNOWN ' ELSE '' END
    ) 'Commands' 
FROM tbl_Version
```

Answer (score 0):

They'rea binary Flag (e.g. Merge, Undelete is Merge+Undelete => 128+32 = 160) the base values are stored in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType` ([docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changetype(v=vs.120).aspx)) and the base value of each change type can be found by either referencing the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` assembly or by reflecting te sources:

```
[Flags]
public enum ChangeType
{
    Add = 2,
    Branch = 128,
    Delete = 32,
    Edit = 4,
    Encoding = 8,
    Lock = 512,
    Merge = 256,
    None = 1,
    Property = 8192,
    Rename = 16,
    Rollback = 1024,
    SourceRename = 2048,
    Undelete = 64
}
```

PS: it looks like your original table has a number of errors in it.